# Implement Not in expression trees, .net 4

Tags: .net-3.5, c#-3.0, expression-trees

Is it possible to implement a ! (not) using expression trees. I'm interested in creating a C# eval class which will parse and evaluate logical expressions which contain true, false, ||, && and !. I know that && and || are currently supported by .NET 4 expression trees,  but I was wondering if their is a way to implement summat like !(x && y) || z where z=false, y=true and z=false.

Currently I'm using a standard stack based tokenizer, parser, evaluator to evaluate these types of expression but would happly dump it, if a suitable expression tree could be created and executed on the fly.

Comment: The title says .NET 4 but the tags say .NET 3.5.  Which one?

Comment: 3.5 When I last checked, it wasn't implemented, but it is now in the docs, so ignore the .net entry.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I usually find that it's worth coding a lambda expression which does what I want, and then seeing what the C# compiler does with it.

So this code:

```
Expression<Func<bool,bool>> func = x => !x;
```

Is compiled into:

```
ParameterExpression expression2;
Expression<Func<bool, bool>> expression = 
       Expression.Lambda<Func<bool, bool>>(Expression.Not(
            expression2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(bool), "x")), 
                new ParameterExpression[] { expression2 });
```

(Apologies for the formatting - it's hard to know what to do with that.)

That's decompiled with Reflector, but with its "optimization" set at .NET 2.0 to avoid it using lambda syntax.

Once you've got past the junk, you'll see it's using [`Expression.Not`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.not.aspx). && uses [`Expression.AndAlso`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.andalso.aspx), and || uses [`Expression.OrElse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.orelse.aspx).

Comment: Hi Jon,
As usual, a quick and superb answer. 
Bob.

Comment: Awesome technique for understanding better what's going on under the hood.

Comment: I originally had the full `!(x && y) || z` but the code it builds is too messy for words :)

Answer (score 2):

This already exists in `System.Linq.Expressions`.  See [UnaryExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.unaryexpression.aspx).  Unless there is something about the expressions that you don't like, I would suggest using them.  There are also ways to create abstract syntax trees from source code, specifically in `Microsoft.Scripting.Ast` (found in the DLR: Microsoft.Scripting).

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful:
http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2009/08/10/expression-trees-take-two-introducing-system-linq-expressions-v4-0.aspx